# Cross Tab form persistence with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, persistence

```
var name = document.getElementById('name');
  name.value = localStorage.name || '';

  name.addEventListener('blur', function() {
    if ( this.value ) localStorage.setItem('name', this.value);
  }); 

  window.addEventListener('storage', function() {
    console.log('updated');
  }, false);
```

The code above is copied directly from a Tuts+ Premium course called HTML5 Fundamentals. My problem is that the Javascript is detecting the localStorage update but is not updating the other tab. In the tutorial, it works flawlessly. I do have a suspicion that this is happening because I'm using .value and firefox has issues with that. I'm running on a Ubuntu 13.04 virtualbox using Firefox version 21.0. Thank you

It turns out that I just needed to add "name.value = localStorage.name;" within the "window.addEventListener('storage', function(e) {" and it worked. Thank you

Comment: _other tab_? what do you mean? [this](http://jsfiddle.net/aTgBT/) seems to be working

Comment: By other tab I mean if I had two tabs open with the same website and I update one of the text boxes the other tabs text box should update automatically to have the same value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test this code in Firefox 22 and it works well:

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" id="input"/>
    <script>
    function onLoad(){
        var name=document.getElementById("input");
        name.value = localStorage.name || '';
        name.addEventListener('blur',function(e){
            if (this.value) {
                localStorage.setItem('name',this.value)
            };
        });

        window.addEventListener('storage',function(){
            console.log('updated');
            name.value = localStorage.name;
        },false);
    }
    window.onload = onLoad();

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And result is....

First tab:

[image]

Second one:

[image]

If you have any further question welcome to discuss.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change input value on another tab edit your `storage` handler:

```
name.value = localStorage.name;
```

instead of

```
console.log('updated');
```

works in Chrome 27.0 and FF 21.0 under Ubuntu 12.04

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/BXKy5/)
(of course you have to open it in 2 tabs to check)